# PHP codes don't work in new version PHP 8.0 -- Undefined variables "$scrollamount" and "$message" in PHP

Tags: php, regex

My php codes work fine with my web pages in PHP 7.0, but after upgrading to PHP 8.0, my php web pages don't work anymore. Here are the errors and warnings below. I am not a programmer. Could you please help me to fix them? Thanks for considering my request. Thanks again. -- Andy

```
[21-Jun-2023 23:17:27 America/New_York]

PHP Warning: Undefined variable $scrollamount in /homepages/d13xxxxx/htdocs/wish/wish.php on line 541
PHP Warning: Undefined variable $scrollamount in /homepages/d13xxxxx/htdocs/wish/wish.php on line 542
PHP Warning: Undefined variable $message in /homepages/d13xxxxx/htdocs/wish/show.php on line 11


// -- **next lines are 541 and 542**

if($scrollamount<=5){

$scrollamount=$scrollamount+1;

} else {

$scrollamount=1;

}

echo "<marquee scrollamount=$scrollamount delay=0><a href=\\"javascript:openChromeslessWindow('show.php?        number=$f\[0\]','data',310,310,null,null,'查看許願內容', '#000000', '#000000', '#999988', '#808040' ,true,'??','1','#000000')\\" ONMOUSEOVER=\\"pop('來自".$f\[7\]."<br>".$f\[6\]."歲的".$f\[1\]."<br>於".$f\[2\]."<br>在這裡許了個願<br>共有".$f\[8\]."個人看過')\\"; ONMOUSEOUT=\\"kill()\\"><img src=\\"images/c".$f\[3\].".gif\\" border=0></a></marquee>";

}
}
?>
```

.
.

```
// ... PHP Warning: Undefined variable "$message", see below:

include "config.inc";

$f=file("database/".$_GET['number']);

for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){

if($i==8)$f[$i]=$f[$i]+1;

// Next line # is 11 -- PHP Warning: Undefined variable "$message" 
$message=$message.$f[$i];

$ff=explode("\n",$f[$i]);

$f[$i]=$ff[0];

}

$fp=fopen("database/".$_GET['number'],"w");

flock($fp,3);

fwrite($fp,$message);

fclose($fp);`
</code>`

(Do not know how to define the variables? I knew it works in PHP 6.0 and PHP 7.0.)
```

Comment: If that's ALL of the code, then just change that line to `$message = $f[$i];`.  For the other one, we can't say without seeing more of the code.  None of these things will stop the code from working.  You may have to hire someone local to chase this.

Comment: If you are not a programmer, you will still don't know what to do after we have give you the solutions.

Comment: Simply initialized the undefine variables before you call in your code.

Comment: The code always raised these errors, you just had them hidden in the config previously. Fix the errors, don't just hide them again.

Comment: I have tried changing the line to $message = $f[$i]; the $message and $scrollamount are still showing undefine variables.

Comment: This is the magic of php 8. The error wants to say you - Catch me if you can. You also need to see php 8 documentation and and updated restrictions.

Comment: `$message=$message.$f[$i];` - you are attempting read access to $message here, so the variable needs to already exist at that point. Just properly initialize it before your loop, `$message = '';` - now you have an empty string in there, that from now on other stuff can be appended to.

Comment: `if($scrollamount<=5)` => `if(isset($scrollamount) && $scrollamount<=5)` should probably do the trick for that part.

Answer (score 0):

For $scrollamount you don't have a previous value so you could use the coalesce operator `??` and if you want to assign a default value you could use something like this:

```
$scrollamout = ($scrollamout ?? 0) <= 5 ? ($scrollamout ?? 0) + 1 : 1;
```

And for $message the same:

```
$message = ($message ?? '') . $f[$i];
```

That way, you are undefined-safe error because you will have a default value in case there's no previous value.

Answer (score -1):

you should declare variable "$scrollamount" and "$message" before loop for
.Example:

```
$message = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){

    if($i==8){
       $f[$i]=$f[$i]+1;        

        $message=$message.$f[$i];
        $ff=explode("\n",$f[$i]);
        $f[$i]=$ff[0];
}
```

}